# Jquery UI autocomplete does not select all field text

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with Jquery UI autocomplete: it only selects the start of the text which is typed in the field (characters preselection), not the whole text. For example : "stra" is selected instead of "strategy".

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
   function doTag(iId, sLibelle) {
       $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        url: "../../bobookmarks/content/json/put_tag_in_session.php", 
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json", 
        data: {iId: iId,
               sLibelle : sLibelle },
        success: function(data) { 
                        if (data=="erreur") { 
                            sErreur = "Une erreur est survenue";  
                            console.log(sErreur + "bo.js:L18"); 
                            alert(sErreur); 
                            return false; 
                        }                               
        }, 

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
           var s = "Une erreur est survenue";   
           alert(s);               
        }
    })  

    var sLi;
    sLi = "<li class=\"tags\">";

    sLi += "<a href=\"#\" title=\"Supprimer ce tag\"><span class=\"label label-primary\">"+$("#tag").val()+"</span></a>";

    sLi += "<a href=\"#\" title=\"Supprimer ce tag\" class=\"form_ajout_tag_suppr\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span></a>";

    sLi += "</li>";

    $("#tags_liste").append(sLi);       

    $("#tag").val("");      
    return true;
 } // -- doTag()

 if ($("#tag").length > 0) {                
    $("#tag").autocomplete({
        minLength:3,
        source: function(request,response) {
                    $.ajax({ 
                        type        : "GET",
                        url         : "../../bobookmarks/content/json/get_tags.php", 
                        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                        dataType    : "json", 
                        data        : { term: $("#tag").val() },
                        success     : function(data) { 
                                        if (data=="erreur") { 
                                            alert("Une erreur est survenue"); 
                                            return false; 
                                        } 

                                        response($.map(data,   function(item) { 
                                            return { id: item.catv_num,
                                                     value: item.catv_v_libelle
                                                   }                            
                                        }) // -- fin response
                                        )}, // -- fin success

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                           var s = "Une erreur est survenue";   
                           console.log(s+" (bo.js:L74)");     
                           alert(s); 
                        }
                    }) // -- fin ajax
        }, // -- fin source

    });     

    $("#tag").on("autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
        $("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val(1);
        console.log("tags_autocomplete_flag val (dans autocompleteresponse) : "+$("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val());    
        doTag(ui.id, ui.value);     
    });

    $("#tag").blur( function() {        

        console.log("tags_autocomplete_flag val (entrée blur) : "+$("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val());    

          if ($("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val()==1) { 
            console.log("tags_autocomplete_flag val (blur(), conditon ==1) : "+$("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val());    
            // Le tag vient de la base (autocomplétion)     
            // la mise en session a déjà été traitée ci-dessus (L80 à 84)   
            // on remet le flag à 0         
            $("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val(0);            
        } else { // Le tag ne vient pas de la base  
            console.log("tags_autocomplete_flag val (si = 0 condition  else) : "+$("#tags_autocomplete_flag").val());    
            doTag(0,  $("#tag").val());         
        }           
    });             
 }
 });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you read the API details for `minLength` yet?

Comment: Yes I do of course but it not seems to be the problem.

Comment: So whats the problem? That seems to be the expected behaivor, is that after 3 characters are typed, the autocomplete will try to find a list of possible selections.

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

`doTag(ui.id, ui.value);`

this is not getting the right content. If you review the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), you will see:

> select( event, ui ) Type: autocompleteselect
>   Triggered when an item is selected from the menu. The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.
>
> Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated, but does
>   not prevent the menu from closing.
>
> **event**
>
> ```
> Type: Event
> ```
>
> **ui**
>
> ```
> Type: Object
> ```
>
> > **item**
> >
> > ```
> > Type: Object
> > An Object with label and value properties for the selected option.
> > ```

You should be calling:

`doTag(ui.id, ui.item.value);`

to get the complete selected value from the AutoComplete list. Tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/bpq3vxd1/